# How do I populate an array with information from a vector and select a random item from the array?

Tags: c++

I need to load the info from the vector into the array, does anyone know how I might be able to do that?

What I am making is something where you can input data onto a text file, than have it pull (number) random items from the list.

I appreciate any help you can provide to me completing this task.

Comment: Why do you need to do that. Also, [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: It would be nice if you format the code use `int main()` inseatd of `tmain` (which is not standard) and remove not needed headers (like 'stdafx.h', 'Windows.h', ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <random>
...
srand( time(NULL) );        // Initializes the random seed
string randFromVector;
randFromVector = vlist[ rand() % vlist.size() ];    // Takes the data at this address
```

rand() provides a random number ("psuedo" random, technically). Then, we use modular on the length of the vlist to make sure it references a legal address.

edit: You only need to initialize the random seed once. Every time you call rand() it will return a different number.

You could also remove the [modulus bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator/10984975#10984975) by doing this:

```
int x;
do {
    x= rand();
} while ( x >= vlist.size() );

randFromVector = vlist[ x];
```

Comment: Well, `rand()` doesn't necessarily return a *different* number every time, but it will get another "random" number. Because it's random, it could be the same, though it's not likely

Comment: @wlyles Furthermore, rand() is technically a "preset" sequence of numbers based on the seed, IIRC. So if someone else somehow got the same seed as you, their "random" numbers would be identical to yours.

Comment: @chris How would I avoid using modulus in this example?